# I am trying to use a Laravel Job Class to send emails on queues but it just kept saying class not found

Tags: laravel

I would appreciate any assistance and if it is of any assistance I am using a laravel multi auth system and i created a folder for admin related controllers. I am trying to use this class in the RegisterController of the Admin Subfolder

I would appreciate any assistance and if it is of any assistance I am using a laravel multi auth system and i created a folder for admin related controllers. I am trying to use this class in the RegisterController of the Admin Subfolder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Agent\Auth;

use App\Agent;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Jobs\AgentMailQueuer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the register form.
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showRegisterForm()
    {
        return view('agent.auth.register',[
            'title' => 'Create A New Agent On This Page.',
            'registerRoute' => 'agent.register',
        ]);
    }



    /**
     * Create a new agent instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Agent
     */
    public function create(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate(request(),[
            'firstname' => 'required|string|max:255|alpha|min:2',
            'lastname' => 'required|string|max:255|alpha|min:2',
            'city' => 'required|max:255|min:2',
            'state' => 'required|string|max:255|alpha|min:2',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:agents',
            'consent' => 'required',
        ]);

        $newAgentId = unique_random('agents', 'aid', 10);
        $newAgentGeneratedPassword = unique_random('agents', 'password', 12);
        $agent = Agent::Create([
            'firstname' => $request['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $request['lastname'],
            'city' => $request['city'],
            'state' => $request['state'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'aid' => $newAgentId,
            'password' => Hash::make($newAgentGeneratedPassword),
        ]);

        // Mailing Info to Agents
        AgentMailQueuer::dispatch($agent);

        return redirect()->to('/agent/register')->with('agentcreated', 'New Agent has been Created and their Credentials have been Succesfully Emailed to them !');

    }
}
```

Comment: Please include code for your job class

Comment: I solved it lol...I changed the name of the Job class lol. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing the name of the `Job` class.

*(answered by questioner)*